# The application "exampleApp" can’t be opened. How to modify the executable status?

Tags: macos, application-launch

Can someone tell me what exactly do I need to do from this explanation?

> After extensive trial-and-error, and a lot of fruitless Googling, I found the solution required modifying the executable status of the "inner" application file. This line:
>
> `chmod +x SomeApp.app/contents/macos/*`
>
> Fixed the problem in all cases that I observed. The `+x` flags a file as executable, and the only file in the `/contents/macos/` directory is a
>   binary representing the actual file that should be executed when you
>   double-click the application (a `.app` file is really just a folder).
>
> Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- launch Terminal [Applications/Utilities], then type or copy/paste
  `chmod +x` [including a space after the x]
- then drag the app you need to change the perms straight onto the Terminal window, which will fill in the correct path
- hit Backspace once, as the last task will add an unnecessary space
- Then you need to add the sub-path to the actual executable inside the app, so copy this & paste it onto the end of your current Terminal line `/Contents/MacOS/*`
- Hit Enter

This will change the permissions to executable.

An example of the  'finished' Terminal command, using TextEdit as the example
`chmod +x /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/*`

*Note:*
Terminal never tells you "Success" or "Done" etc. If you see it add a new line saying
`yourMac:~ yourname$` then it's finished.
If there's an error it will report that.

If you get an error saying you do not have permission to do this, then start over, but use
`sudo chmod +x` for the first step.
This is, in effect, "Administrator Override" mode.
You will be asked to provide your Mac password when you hit Enter [which will not show at all as you type it] then hit Enter again.

Comment: in Linux at least you can use `stat` following your chmod command to check new permissions - that is; read, write and execute. https://ss64.com/osx/stat.html seems to suggest that `stat` is available in macOS as well - maybe this can be of use to OP.

Comment: `stat` will give you the octal. `ls -l` will show you the simple perms `drwxr-x--x+` etc. `ls -le` will give you full including ACLs.